# Writing a formula to a cell with OpenXLS

Tags: java, excel, openxls

I'm using Java and OpenXLS to write out an Excel spreadsheet.  I want to set a formula for a cell but I haven't got a clue how to do it.  Can anybody help me, please? :)

(Can't tag this with "openxls" because I'm a new user...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about OpenXLS, but it's easy to do with Andy Khan's [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).  I'd recommend trying it.  I think it's far superior to POI; I'm betting that it's better than OpenXLS as well.

Comment: Ultimately I did swap to JExcel.  Turns out that OpenXLS doesn't support formulae at all - if you want to use them then you need to upgrade to the paid version :(

Answer (score 2):

OpenXLS support very well formulas. Look at this example.
I put a value in the columns A and B of a sheet named "testSheet". In the column C of the same sheet I put the result of SUM (A+B).Don't forget to initialise the column C else you will have a CellNotFoundException

```
WorkBookHandle workbook = new WorkBookHandle();
workbook.createWorkSheet("testSheet");
WorkSheetHandle sheet = workbook.getWorkSheet("testSheet");
for (int i=1 ;i<=10; i++)
 {
    sheet.add(10*i, "A"+i);
    sheet.add(15*i, "B"+i);
    CellHandle cx = sheet.add(0,"C"+i);
    cx.setFormula("=SUM(A"+i+":B"+i+")");
 }
```

I hope that that this example will help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it turned out that OpenXLS doesn't support formula cells.  They are included in the paid for version, though...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the formula String directly on the cell in the Worksheet:

```
CellHandle cell = ws.add( "=SUM(A1:A3)", "A5" );
```

This adds the SUM(A1:A3) formula in cell A5.  Any Cell set with a String value that is prefixed with '=' is considered a Formula.

Updates and maintenance are now happening on github (search for openxls).